# Giant Bomb API Json

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I'm trying to use the Giant Bomb API. I also use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the response object. I've a problem when I try to convert the response to classes. I've a problem with something who looks like an array. I don't understand what it exactly is and which using ref i should use to make it work ...

Here is the syntax : `public ApiSearchResult[] results { get; set; }`

Here is the tutorial : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26920.winrt-using-giant-bomb-api-to-get-games-information.aspx

Comment: Not the right place to ask about external tutorials. Sorry.

Comment: That's the first time i ask a question here so i didn't know. Could you move it to the right place ? If we can't ask questions about tuts here, maybe i can just delete the tuts link ?

Comment: Try to get in touch with the author of that tutorial. Removing the link doesn't help, since it looks like `ApiSearchResult` is not a well-known class (e.g., from a .NET library).

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Are you getting it when you attempt to deserizlise from JSON to a C# class? Also, could you post the relevant section of the raw JSON?

Comment: Just a  “type or namespace name could not be found”. I probably need to add a using ref to make it work but i can't find which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the documentation, it appears that `ApiSearchResult` is supposed to be `Result`.  Try changing `public ApiSearchResult[] results { get; set; }` to
`public Result[] results { get; set; }`.

Comment: It seems to work, but when i try to read the array, values are " WpfApplication7.App+Result " and nothing from the Json answer. 

Here is what I do :

`gamesFound = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<App.RootObject>(jsonData);

foreach (var game in gamesFound.results)
{
  App.ApiGamesList.Add(game);
  System.Console.WriteLine(game);
}`

Comment: `game` is a `Result` object.  Try something like `System.Console.WriteLine(game.name);`

Comment: It works :). Thanks, you are my hero of the day ! I'll try to go further and see if i've other problems :).

Comment: I want to show the result stored in an observableCollection "ApiGamesList". in a datagrid. Do you know how I could dynamically ask my datagrid columns to become image columns when they will receive images ?

For the moment i just to `mydatagrid.ItemsSource = App.ApiGamesList;` to show data in my datagrid.